# Binary 16 bit signed 2's complement system?

Tags: binary

For an assignment the question is "What is the range of positive numbers and negative numbers represented by a 16-bit signed 2's compliment system? I've tried looking it up and I can't figure it out.

Comment: You could calculate this yourself... from `-2^15` to `2^15-1`

Comment: Ask yourself the question: what is the bit pattern of the largest positive number? What is the pattern of the lowest negative number? Then just convert those binary numbers to decimal.